# problema validacion form con js para enviar por post php

Tags: php, javascript, formularios, validación

tengo este form:

```
<form action="../procedimientos/guardar_familiar.php" onsubmit="return verificarFormulario" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Primer apellido <b>*</b> : </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_1" id="apellido_1" placeholder="Introduce el primer apellido">   
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button id="btn_guardar_familiar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-100 py-100">Guardar</button>       
    </div>
</form>


<script>
        function verificarFormulario () {

        var campo_apellido_1 = document.getElementById("apellido_1");

        if (campo_apellido_1.value.trim().length == 0) {
            // toastr.warning('Warning','Hola mund');
            //alert("INVALIDO");
            toastr.warning('El primero apellido no puede estar vacio!','Error');
            return false;
        };

                //alert("VALIDO");
                return true;
        }

</script>
```

Si no esta completo el campo `apellido_1` te manda el **toastr** bien, pero cuando esta completo no me lo guarda al llamar al **fichero php**. El **fichero.php** funciona porque lo he probado con otras cosas, pero ahora que le he metido la validacion con **js** ya no llo guarda **cuando el campo apellido_1 esta relleno**.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir también el código PHP?

Comment: Tal como te respondieron debes invocar a la funcion llamandola con los respectivos parentesis: "verificarFormulario()"....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siempre debería invocarse la función con paréntesis:

```
<form action="../procedimientos/guardar_familiar.php" onsubmit="return verificarFormulario()" method="post">
```

Con ese cambio debería funcionar, te recomiendo darle una mirada a [este ejemplo](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/validate%20the%20form%20data%20before%20and%20after%20submitting%20the%20form.php) que funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Compadrito, no se mucho sobre js, pero creo que te faltan los paréntesis en onsubmit="return verificarFormulario()" y colocar dentro de un else el return.

```
<form action="testok.php" onsubmit="return verificarFormulario()" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Primer apellido <b>*</b> : </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_1" id="apellido_1" placeholder="Introduce el primer apellido">   
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button id="btn_guardar_familiar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-100 py-100">Guardar</button>       
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function verificarFormulario () {

        var campo_apellido_1 = document.getElementById("apellido_1");

        if (campo_apellido_1.value.trim().length == 0) {
            // toastr.warning('Warning','Hola mund');
            //alert("INVALIDO");
            //toastr.warning('El primero apellido no puede estar vacio!','Error');
            return false;

        }
        else {
            //alert("VALIDO");
            return true;
        }              
    }

</script>
```

Comment: En teoría el else no hace falta, porque si no entra al if, hará ese segundo return, y si entra hará el primero. Ya sabes que una vez se detona el return se detiene la ejecución del resto de función JS.